# Nodelets creation

Tags: nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, im tryng to implement nodelets with pcl, can someone help me with a basic example on how to create a nodelet?, i already read about the pluginlib and the nodelet from the wiki ros page, still i have not been able to create a nodelet. Please i would really apreciate some help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31486/nodelets-creation/) by [Alekzander](https://answers.ros.org/users/2145/alekzander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote one recently. A separate [`Convert`](http://code.google.com/p/utexas-art-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/stacks/velodyne/velodyne_pointcloud/src/conversions/convert.h) class does the work, and a minimal [node](http://code.google.com/p/utexas-art-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/stacks/velodyne/velodyne_pointcloud/src/conversions/cloud_node.cc) and [nodelet](http://code.google.com/p/utexas-art-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/stacks/velodyne/velodyne_pointcloud/src/conversions/cloud_nodelet.cc) instantiate it. For several reasons, I find it convenient to have both.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alekzander](https://answers.ros.org/users/2145/alekzander/) on 2012-04-08**:
Thanks a lot that's very illustrative, just one more question, the onInit method is kind of the same as: int main()?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-09**:
It is not like main.  It should return quickly.  It will be called when the nodelet has been created to allow you to setup operations.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-09**:
@tfoote makes an important point. Don't think of onInit() as main(), it's really just the constructor, which should return immediately.